# Group By but then query on the aggregation list

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

If I have two tables:

```
Users      Labels
-----      ------
id           id
           user_id
```

and users and one to many to labels.

I want to say, "give me all users with label=1 or label=2 but not label=3", so a user with labels [1, 5, 6] would be valid, [2, 5, 6] would be valid, but [2, 3, 4] would not be valid.

How would I go about doing this?  I am currently using `array_agg` and `unnest` but I would like to do this without array operations.

```
WITH (
    SELECT user_id, ARRAY_AGG(id) as labels from label
) as labels_agg

SELECT id FROM users
LEFT JOIN labels_agg ON id=user_id
WHERE 1 in UNNEST(labels) and 2 in UNNEST(labels) and 3 not in UNNEST(labels)
```

Comment: I was working in BigQuery, but I wanted to improve portability/performance by removing commands like ARRAY_AGG and UNNEST.   In the future I'll pick a specific version that doesn't have these commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> with label=1 or label=2 but not label=3

I recommend `group by` and `having` for this sort of query:

```
select l.user_id
from labels l
where l.id in (1, 2, 3)
group by l.user_id
having sum(case when l.id in (1, 2) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when l.id in (3) then 1 else 0 end) = 0 ;
```

The `having` clause with conditional aggregation is quite flexible.  The `sum(case . . . )` counts the number of mentioned labels for each user id.  The `> 0` says that at least one exists.  The `= 0` says that none exist.

In this case, you can actually simplify the logic to:

```
select l.user_id
from labels l
where l.id in (1, 2, 3)
group by l.user_id
having max(l.id) in (1, 2);
```

That happens to work for these ids, but is not as generalizable.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `not exists`.

```
SELECT l1.user_id, l1.id as labels 
from label l1
where id in (1,2)
and not exists (select 1 from label l2 where l1.user_id=l2.user_id and l2.id = 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the desired results using EXCEPT.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT usr.id AS UserId, lbl.id AS Label_Id FROM Users usr LEFT 
JOIN Labels lbl ON
usr.id = lbl.[user_id] 
)
SELECT UserId FROM cte WHERE
Label_Id IN (1,2) 
EXCEPT
SELECT UserId FROM cte WHERE
Label_Id IN (3)
```

Here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/791cd/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT user_id
FROM labels
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNTIF(id IN (1, 2)) > 0 
AND COUNTIF(id = 3) = 0
```